Hooks for received emails
Main goal: I would like my PHP script to parse and take action on incoming mails that land in certain folders

I use a mail client that lets me edit a sieve filter which moves emails into different folders

To my limited understanding, sieve runs independently of the mail client

For some of incoming emails, I would like to parse them for some info and further move them into another folder called processed

Currently, what I do is to have an PHP IMAP client connected constantly to IMAP and monitor for new mails, but this is not scalable.

I did explore another option which was adding to /etc/postfix/master.cf, but I was not able to figure out how it would interact with sieve

forwardhook unix - n n - - pipe
  flags=F user=user-data argv=/my/php/script1.php ${recipient} ${sender} ${size}



My 3 related questions would be:

What is the order of execution for sieve and script1.php?
Is it possible to call script1.php from sieve?
In case script1.php messes up the parsing due to changes in the email content/structure, I would like to re-parse them by moving the mails to a specific folder. The PHP IMAP client is able to handle this. How can I do the same with postfix/sieve?


As I understand it, the PHP script will do some work that the sieve can do. They should not operate on the same mails. Then the order doesn't matter. I would look into inotifywait: that is a command that monitors certain directories for changes, and calls a certain command (php script1.php) in case of a change.

thanks, but I think this would be similar to running an IMAP client with scaling limits on how many folders one can watch

You need to understand more how mail delivery works.
When a mail is coming to your server, it is received by a MTA (Message Transfer Agent - for example Postfix), which then passes it on to a LDA (Local Delivery Agent - for example Dovecot, although Postfix itself also can perform this role for simple cases) for delivery to user's mailbox.
Sieve filters are run from inside LDA, before the message is placed in user's mailbox. There can be also some filters (like Milters) run from inside MTA itself, or placed between MTA and LDA (in Postfix terms, these are called after-queue content filters), but these are normally not accessible to an end user from a mail client; they need to be configured directly on the server - like you tried to do with configuring a service in master.cf file. But besides just configuring a service you need to actually call it somewhere inside Postfix mail flow. Service defined the way you did it (in master.cf) is mostly suited to run as an after-queue filter, ie. between MTA and LDA. You can find examples in Postfix documentation. But at that stage of mail flow the filter doesn't know anything about the mailboxes. All it knows is the data concerning the message itself. The after-queue filter can modify the message, reject it or just silently discard, but it cannot deliver it to a particular mailbox, unless you implement that functionality yourself, basically duplicating/replacing the LDA functionality by your content filter.
After-queue filter cannot interact with sieve, as sieve is run within LDA, and after-queue filter is run by MTA, ie. at earlier stage of mail flow.
But the content filter can eg. add a particular header indicating that the message has been processed, and based on the presence of that particular header the sieve filter in LDA can later deliver the message to processed folder.
After the messages are placed in your mailbox, mail client comes into play. Now your IMAP client can read and operate on messages. So I guess this answers your question 1) about in what order they are run.
As for question 2), it is generally possible to run any executable program/script from sieve, but this requries some configuration of sieve that seems a bit complicated for me at a first glance (I just googled that; I never used sieve as i use procmail for my mail processing - it's considered obsolete, but still does the job perfectly for me), but you almost certainly couldn't run your script1.php without changes, as it probably needs to be adapted to how the message is fed to it by sieve vs. how it is done currently, and how the message is then moved to processed folder (I assume you currently do it via IMAP, in sieve you definitely will have to do it another way).
As for 3), your question is not clear to me. Are you asking how to move mail to a specific folder using sieve? If yes, then you need to look that up in the sieve documentation. I can't answer as I haven't used sieve, as I already mentioned.
Generally, if you want to do such operations, you should start with thorough understanding how the tools you are dealing with work in details. And that means: reading the documentation, experimenting, reading the documentation, experimenting, and again reading the documentation and experimenting. Nobody here can give you a "recipe" you can just copy, because nobody knows, in the first place, the details of your mail setup. And these matter a lot in such cases.
Hope this helps.

Thanks for your very detailed explanation and also reminding me of procmail, I have tried over the years to understand emails but never gotten far. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509542/3872647, based on your answer, I gather procmail (like sieve) is also running inside the LDA.


is asking if there is any simple/easy way to put selected messages through sieve/procmail/script1.php again for re-parsing (moving of the message into a folder was to explain how IMAP client does it, e.g. if I move 3 messages into folder A, client will re-parse them again because 3 messages appeared, after parsing, they will be moved elsewhere)


Neither sieve nor procmail operate on messages that are already in folder. They operate on messages while they are in transit, and finally can decide to file a message into some folder. That is a final action - after a message is filed into a folder, sieve/procmail processing ends.
I can't understand the reason for feeding the same message into the same script again if processing failed for the first time - why do you expect the result to be different the next time, if the message didn't change? (The fact that it is filed into a folder does not change the contents).

It will be different because I will modify script1.php to fix the parsing. Senders do make changes over time.

So it's not a part of the same process. One process, performed routinely on incoming messages, is filtering mail messages, processing them through your script, and filing into appropriate folders. In case this process fails, you need some time to modify your script, and then perform another "troubleshooting" process, which involves re-parsing messages with a modified script and moving them to a different folder. These are two distinctively different processes and they should remain separate, you should not try to merge them into a single process as this makes no sense.

(cont.) I understand that the "troubleshooting" process will be performed only occasionally, after something goes wrong. As it requires your manual intervention anyway (modifying the script), it is probably best, after you have modified the script, to manually resend the failed messages back to yourself. As incoming messages, they will be processed by your (modified) script and filed into the processed folder, after which you can manually delete them from the folder they were previously.

my q3 comes from the angle where developer fixes script1, but user themselves decide/control how to handle those wrongly parsed emails, for that, a UI is needed, and now possibly, running a IMAP client for every one of them vs 1 instance for all users
